# Given, a matrix representation of a linear transformation, find a formula for it and represent it by a matrix with respect to a given ordered basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Suppose the matrix of the linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3$ with respect to the standard ordered basis of $\Bbb R^3$ is $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 && 2 && 3\\ 3&& 1 && -5\\ 0 && 0 && 1\end{pmatrix}.$ Find $T(x,y,z)$ for any $(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3$ and find the matrix $B$ (say) of $T$ with respect to the
ordered basis $\gamma=\{(1,1,0).(0,0,1),(0,1,1)\}.$

My solution goes like this:

Given, the matrix of the linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3$ with respect to the standard ordered basis of $\Bbb R^3$ is $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 && 2 && 3\\ 3&& 1 && -5\\ 0 && 0 && 1\end{pmatrix}.$

This means $T(1,0,0)=(1,3,0),T(0,1,0)=(2,1,0)$ and $T(0,0,1)=(3,-5,1).$

Thus, for $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3$ we have, $T(x,y,z)=xT(1,0,0)+yT(0,1,0)+zT(0,0,1)=(x+2y+3z,3x+y-5z,z).$

Let $e_1=(1,1,0),e_2=(0,0,1),e_3=(0,1,1).$

This means $$T(1,1,0)=(3,4,0)=3e_1+-e_2+e_3,$$$$T(0,0,1)=(3,-5,1)=3e_1+9e_2-8e_3$$ and $$T(0,1,1)=(5,-4,1)=5e_1+10e_2-9e_3.$$

Thus, $$B=[T]_{\gamma}=\begin{pmatrix}3 && 3 && 5\\ -1 && 9 && 10\\ 1 && -8 && -9\end{pmatrix}.$$

---

Does the above solution needs some improvement? Any suggestions regarding the modifications that I can make to improve the readability of the solution will be greatly appreciated. Lastly, is the above solution correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is fine. Note that, when you're working with the canonical base, to find the transformation you can read the coefficient of the matrix. For example, if you want the first entry of $T(x,y,z)$, reading the coefficients of the first row you get : $x+2y+3z$ . Moreover, to compute the image of a vector, you can multiply it to the matrix. For example:
$$T((1,1,0))=A\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 && 2 && 3\\ 3&& 1 && -5\\ 0 && 0 && 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\\0\end{pmatrix} $$